# MySQL 5.6: Complex Query with Grouped Parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm far from a MYSQL expert, and I'm struggling with a relatively complicated query.

I have two tables:

A Data table with columns as follows:

```
`Location` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Source` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Param` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Type` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`InitTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`ValidTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`Value` double DEFAULT NULL
```

A Location Group table with columns as follows:

```
`Group` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`Location` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

The data table stores data of interest, where each 'value' is valid for a particular 'validtime'. However, the data in the table comes from a calculation which is run periodically. The initialisation time at which the calculation is run is stored in the 'inittime' field. A given calculation with particular inittime may result in, say 10 values being output with valid times (A - J). A more recent calculation, with a more recent inittime, may result in another 10 values being output with valid times (B - K). There is therefore an overlap in available values. I always want a result set of Values and ValidTimes for the most recent inittime (i.e. max(inittime)).

I can determine the most recent inittime using the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(InitTime)
FROM Data
WHERE
  Location = 100060 AND
  Source = 10 AND
  Param = 1 AND
  Type = 1;
```

This takes 0.072 secs to execute.

However, using this as a sub-query to retrieve data from the Data table results in an execution time of 45 seconds (it's a pretty huge table, but not super ridiculous).

Sub-Query:

```
SELECT Location, ValidTime, Value
FROM Data data
WHERE Source = 10
    AND Location IN (SELECT Location FROM Location Group WHERE Group = 3)
    AND InitTime = (SELECT max(data2.InitTime) FROM Data data2 WHERE data.Location = data2.Location AND data.Source = data2.Source AND data.Param = data2.Param AND data.Type = data2.Type)
ORDER BY Location, ValidTime ASC;
```

(Snipped ValidTime qualifiers for brevity)

I know there's likely some optimisation that would help here, but I'm not sure where to start. Instead, I created a stored procedure to effectively perform the MAX(InitTime) query, but because the MAX(InitTime) is determined by a combo of Location, Source, Param and Type, I need to pass in all the locations that comprise a particular group. I implemented a cursors-based stored procedure for this before realising there must be an easier way.

Putting aside the question of optimisation via indices, how could I efficiently perform a query on the data table using the most recent InitTime for a given location group, source, param and type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can do a poor job optimizing `IN` with a subquery (sometimes).  Also, indexes might be able to help.  So, I would write the query as:

```
SELECT d.Location, d.ValidTime, d.Value
FROM Data d
WHERE d.Source = 10 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LocationGroup lg WHERE d.Location = lg.Location and lg.Group = 3) AND
      d.InitTime = (SELECT max(d2.InitTime)
                    FROM Data d2
                    WHERE d.Location = d2.Location AND
                          d.Source = d2.Source AND
                          d.Param = d2.Param AND
                          d.Type = d2.Type
                   )
ORDER BY d.Location, d.ValidTime ASC;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `data(Location, Source, Param, Type, InitTime)` and `LocationGroup(Location, Group)`, and `data(Source, Location, ValidTime)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using toad to test this, and have similar execution times after implementing this. However, the results pane updates periodically rather than in one big lump at the end.